# for loop putting two similar entries in one loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I wrote a code according to which I can write one XML file into number of XML files depending on number of records.

I have 14 records in one XML file having different tags in XML file.

I am trying to create XML files having having 2 records each, so in the end I should be having 7 XML files.

But instead that I'm getting 14 files only, each file having two similar records.

Following is my XML format, which is getting created dynamically. Format is coming correctly. But two similar entries are coming in each file. So instead of 7 its writing 14 files.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <Product>
    <PID>SGLDN7XJ2FPZH8G8</PID>
    <PNAME>Miami Blues Aviator Sunglasses</PNAME>
  </Product>
</data>
```

Following is my file which is making XML files. I think something is wrong in initializing the for loop:

```
$docOutput = new DOMDocument("1.0");

$root = $docOutput->createElement("data");
$docOutput->appendChild($root);

if (!$sxmlReading = simplexml_load_file('firstxml.xml')) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Error reading XML file');
}

$x      = 0;
foreach ($sxmlReading as $syn) {

    for ($i = $x * 2; $i < ($x + 1) * 2; $i++) {

        $id     = $docOutput->createElement("PID");

        $idText = $docOutput->createTextNode($syn->productId);
        $id->appendChild($idText);

        $title     = $docOutput->createElement("PNAME");
        $titleText = $docOutput->createTextNode($syn->productname);
        $title->appendChild($titleText);

        $book = $docOutput->createElement("Product");
        $book->appendChild($id);
        $book->appendChild($title);

        $root->appendChild($book);

        $docOutput->formatOutput = true;
        echo "<xmp>" . $docOutput->saveXML() . "</xmp>";

        $docOutput->save("xml$x.xml") or die("Error");

    }
    $x++;
}
```

Please check the code and highlight my mistake...

Comment: `$i++`. if $x is 5, then you're doing `for($i = 0; $i < (5+1)*2; $i++)`, which is `0 -> 12`, doing `0,1,2,3,4,5,...11`. If you want to go by twos, then you'd need at least `$i += 2` instead of just `$i++`.

Comment: but i m setting $x=0,initially and then in each loop i m incrementing it by 1 ,so if $x is 5 then $i will be equal to 10.so limit will be from from 10-12,isnt it sir?.So according to u,what should be the for loop initialization

Comment: Yes, but $i is initialized to `$i = $x*2` ONCE at the start of the loop. That particular code never executes again, so no matter what you do with $x later on in the loop, $i will always be starting out at 0. The `($x+1)*2` will change the termination conditions on each iteration, but $i itself will only ever go 0,1,2....

Comment: k.so what should i change here sir?

Answer (score 0):

It is writing 14 files because you are calling the `DOMDocument::save()` method 14 times.

Sounds more like a typo to me honestly, I can not see anything wrong with that. PHP just does as you've written it to do.

Comment: i moved save function outside forloop,but still its making 14 files

Comment: Yes my fault, it's already the case that you do 14 iterations in the *outer* loop already, as written, I think it's just some typo/simple mistake you made in your code, nothing a little debugging wouldn't trouble shoot. I do not see much of a concrete programming question here. Perhaps you can share more and make it more specific? (corrected my "answer" as well)